# Google Data Studio get previous row value for specific colum

Tags: google-bigquery, dashboard, looker-studio

I'am new to Google Data Studio (Looker Studio) and I would like to get the previous row value for any column. For example I have the following database:

| Month | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 42 |
| 4 | 33 |
| 5 | 78 |
| 6 | 11 |

I would like to create a field on my database that looks like this:

| Month | Value | Previous Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | Nan |
| 2 | 42 | 34 |
| 4 | 33 | 42 |
| 5 | 78 | 33 |
| 6 | 11 | 78 |

Does anyone knows how to do it using the calculated field option in Google Data Studio?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around to do a similar thing and a hack worked for me.
Got the inspiration from this [topic](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Technical-Tips-Tricks/Calculating-Moving-Averages/ta-p/587528).

**STEP 1**:
I did a custom calculation with offset list.

```
offset_list(${v_col.impr},-1,1)
```

> **offset_list** takes three arguments: the column from which you want to
> grab the offset values, how far from the current row you want to start
> the offset, and how long you want the offset list to be.

**STEP 2**:
I got the LEAD values but was not able to visualize or use it like linear series.
Got the error that it can't combine linear and category series.

Since it is just a single value LEAD, therefore, used mean over it and got a linear series.

```
mean(offset_list(${v_col.impr},-1,1))
```

If you just want to view it as a LEAD series you can stop at STEP 1.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

To get the previous row value for a specific column in Google Data Studio, you can use the `LAG()` function in a calculated field. For example, the following calculated field formula would return the previous row value for the `MonthValue` column:

```
LAG(MonthValue, 1)
```

You can then use the calculated field in your reports and visualizations.

Comment: Hello Syed! thanks for you reply. Unfortunately I cannot use this function. I'm using https://lookerstudio.google.com/ but when I try to use it I get the following error: Unsupported operator: LAG